# Center image both horizontally and vertically

Tags: html, css

I have 2 images on my homepage that are centered vertically with this.

```
#pgc-10-1-1.panel-grid-cell {
display: inline-block;
float: none !important;
vertical-align: middle;
```

}

```
#pgc-10-3-0.panel-grid-cell {
display: inline-block;
float: none !important;
vertical-align: middle;
```

}

However, I want them to be centered both horizontally and vertically.
When I don't use `float: none !important;`, the image is centered horizontally, but not vertically. When I use `float: none !important;`, the image is centered vertically but not horizontally.
How can I have it centered both horizontally and vertically at the same time? Thanks!

```
<div class="panel-grid-cell" id="pgc-10-1-1" >
  <div class="so-panel widget widget_sow-editor panel-first-child panel-last-child" id="panel-10-1-1-0">
    <div class="so-widget-sow-editor so-widget-sow-editor-base">
      <div class="siteorigin-widget-tinymce textwidget">
        <p>
          <img style="text-align: center;" src="site" width="208" height="208" />
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you please include a HTML snippet.

Comment: you should include this in your question; not in the comments.

Comment: Dont have time atm to answer the whole question but where i work the use of !important is just a straight no no. And would only be used if you are doing some very basic overrides.

Comment: Just give `#pgc-10-1-1.panel` and `#pgc-10-3-0` `width:100%` for your `max-width:768px` media query..I guess that should alin your images

Answer (score 1):

According to your code snippet, I've taken a short look into your website. You are currently nesting a few `div`s into each other. To achieve what you want, you have to set `text-align: center;` in your parental container. In your case, you have 2 child `div`s inside of your parent, which (both together) take 100 % of your parent `div`s width.

As a short example, you may use `display: none;` (just to hide that `div`) on the `div` with the text and `text-align: center;` on your parent one. After that, your image should be centered. After doing so, you may see that your `div` containing the text has to be smaller. If you want the text to appear below your image, just use `display: block;` on the text `div`.

Comment: You're welcome! If you've any further questions, just go ahead. If not, I'm glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

```css
#pgc-10-1-1.panel-grid-cell {
  display: block;
  float: none !important;
  background-color: blue;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  position: absolute;
}

#pgc-10-1-1.panel-grid-cell > div{
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  }

#pgc-10-3-0.panel-grid-cell {
  display: inline-block;
  float: none !important;
  vertical-align: middle; 
}
```

```html
<div class="panel-grid-cell" id="pgc-10-1-1" >
  <div class="so-panel widget widget_sow-editor panel-first-child panel-last-child" id="panel-10-1-1-0">
    <div class="so-widget-sow-editor so-widget-sow-editor-base"><div class="siteorigin-widget-tinymce textwidget">
      <p>
        <img style="text-align: center;" src="site" width="208" height="208" />
      </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```